# ¿Como seleccionar un archivo interno aleatoriamente de una carpeta y luego lo Guardo? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, random, rutas

Hola me presento Soy Tomas un usuario nuevo en Stack, he llegado aqui por esta cuestionante que tengo, estoy realizando un proyecto Personal en C# en lo que respecta quiero que este programa seleccione de Forma aleatoria un archivo de una carpeta interna del proyecto (Cualquier tipo de archivo por ejemplo zip, rar o PSD), lo mantenga y luego lo guarde en otro directorio.

- Estoy Usando Forms.

Saludos :)

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrarnos que intentaste hasta el momento y donde tuviste errores?

Comment: Es bastante sencillo lo que quieres, pero necesitamos saber que has intentado para descartar cosas que pueden no funcionar y que ya has probado. En general, en el sitio se pide un poco de investigación previa y esfuerzo antes de recibir respuestas. Te recomiendo que pulses en [edit] y añadas más información a la pregunta y estaremos encantados de ayudarte. Bienvenido a [es.so]!

Answer (score 2):

Para seleccionar archivos random podria usa algo como ser

```
 //obtienes la lista de archivos de la carpeta
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("<ruta origen>", "*.*");

 int index = Random.Next(0, files.Length);

 string file = files[index];

 File.Copy(file, "<aqui path destino>");
```

algo de doc sobre estos metodos

[Random.Next (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Directory.GetFiles (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No es muy difícil hacer lo que quieres aquí te anexo mi solución, te explico.

Lo primero que debes hacer es definir tus rutas de `origen` y `destino` dentro del proyecto. Cuando tengas definidas tus rutas, obtienes la **información del directorio** donde esta la ruta de `destino` a ese directorio, le preguntas por los **archivos** que contiene y  te devolverá un **arreglo** con todo.

A ese arreglo le aplicaras un `random` con la **cantidad de archivos** que contiene el **directorio**, cuando tengas el archivo seleccionado defines tus rutas de `origen` y `destino` para copiar solamente ese archivo. En caso de que no tengas la carpeta creada, esta se creara automáticamente con una condición.

```
try
{
    //DEFINIR LAS RUTAS DE ORIGEN Y DESTINO
    string source = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\Carpeta"));
    string target = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\Carpeta2"));
    //OBTENER LA INFORMACIÓN DEL DIRECTORIO DONDE SE ENCUENTRAN LOS ARCHIVOS
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(source);
    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
    //APLICAR METODO ALEATORIO PARA SELECCIONAR LOS ARCHIVOS DEL ARREGLO
    Random rand = new Random();
    FileInfo file = files[rand.Next(files.Count())];
    //DEFINIR LAS RUTAS DE ORIGEN Y DESTINO CON EL ARCHIVO SELECCIONADO
    string fileName = file.Name;
    string sourceFile = Path.Combine(source, fileName);
    string destFile = Path.Combine(target, fileName);
    //CREAR DIRECTORIO SI NO EXISTE
    if (!Directory.Exists(target))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
    //COPIAR EL ARCHIVO A LA RUTA DESTINO INDICADA CON SU RESPECTIVO ARCHIVO
    File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    MessageBox.Show("Se ha copiado correctamente el archivo.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Me he permitido editar tu respuesta para que sea un poco mas legible. Espero que no te moleste, un saludo.